# CloudFront 504 error: LB security group inbound restrictred only to CloudFront security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-cloudfront

I have followed this link to setup CloudFront SG: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudfront-samples/tree/master/update_security_groups_lambda.
After that edited LB SG to receive inbound traffic only from created CloudFront SG.
Now, it's giving 504 Errors.
Increased response timeout settings on CloudFront, didn't fix the error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your load balancer is giving 504?

Comment: No, error is coming from CloudFront. I think CloudFront can't reach the origin.

Answer (score 0):

It's allowing when attaching these SG directly to LB, without nesting them in one SG as SG rules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).